# Push data to new page dynamically in PDF using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am working with C# and Itextsharp to genereate PDF.

I am having a for loop and want to set image with some text till loop ends. Sometimes loop has 3 rows, sometimes 5 or sometimes more than that.
if data exceeds then i wants automatically push data to new page but it remains on same page.

Image shown below

[image]

I am currently using PdfContentByte to display text.
For this problem i have found solution using tables but i dont want to use that.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: `PdfContentByte` pretty much assumes that you're going to take care of everything including calculating locations and dimensions as well as adding pages. Is there any reason that you can't use the much simpler abstractions like `Paragraph` or `PdfPTable` that do all of this for you automatically? Also, in regard to not wanting to use tables, if you're doing that because you come from an HTML background where we've been told that "tables are evil", that rule doesn't apply here. PDFs don't actually support tables, iText just uses them to handle things that _look_ like rows or columns.

Comment: i am new to ITextsharp & just wanted to know that if there is any other simplest way to do this task other than tables.

Comment: The general abstractions (like `Paragraph` and `PdfPTable`) are definitely the simplest when starting out. They calculate things automatically for you and handle all concepts of "flow" that you'd expect from simple document creation. `PdfContentByte` has a couple of abstractions that you can use with it but generally you should avoid it unless you have a specific need that the abstractions can't solve. Just to reiterate, in iText, _tables aren't necessarily bad_ and in fact they are often the better solution for many things.